# Curl 400 error when using UserAgent

Tags: php, http, curl, user-agent

Why i'm getting sometimes this error?

```
**Bad Request**

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Apache Server at control.digitalcoding.com Port 80
```

When

```
$UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11";
```

everything works fine, but not with

Opera/7.52 (Windows NT 5.1; U) [en]
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1

for example. What is the problem?

**HtmlReciever.php**

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET["Link"]))
{
    echo "empty";
    die;
}
$LinkToFetch = urldecode($_GET["Link"]);
$UserAgent = urldecode($_GET["UserAgent"]);


function iscurlinstalled() 
{
    if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// If curl is instaled
if(iscurlinstalled()==true)
{
    $ch = curl_init($LinkToFetch);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$UserAgent); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $HtmlCode = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
else
{

    $HtmlCode = file_get_contents($LinkToFetch);
}

echo $HtmlCode;
?>
```

I must say that i'm running RecieverHtml.php from another .php with GET like this

http://127.0.0.1/reciever/RecieverHtml.php?Link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalcoding.com%2Ftools%2Fdetect-browser-settings.html&UserAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+rv%3A10.0.1%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F10.0.1%0D%0A

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the server your request is sent to. If the server checks the user agent and allows only requests that match a limited/incomplete/outdated list of common browser user agents, the server might return a generic 400 status code.

If you don't have control over the server and want your script to work, use the user agent that works and forget about the others. The user agent you provide with your request is "wrong" anyway, as it is not Chrome doing the actual request but your server running your PHP script.

EDIT:
You can also pass the user agent of the browser that requests your PHP script by using the following code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_REQUEST['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Just keep in mind that the value might be empty or exotic (like. Lynx/2.8.8dev.3 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1) and be rejected by the server.

Comment: So, are you saying that i need to be in Chrome when i'm executing that script in order to work? This is not good .. and how i can "spoof" a UserAgent by modify my script/server ? I have full access.

Comment: @RowMinds: You don't need to "be" in Chrome. When you pass the user agent you mentioned above (the one that works) you actually pretend to be Chrome, even thought you are a PHP script. You can spoof a user agent by just taking the one sent by Chrome (as you already did), Firefox or whatever browser you want. See my update answer for more details.